# Is watching football matches haram?

Tags: halal-haram, sports

In football matches, people wear shorts and reveal their upper side of leg but revealing awrah is haram. I think it's haram for different reasons but I want to be sure.

Comment: There is a difference of opinion on " what is the arwah of a man " : (1) navel till knees (2) below navel till knees (3) neither naval nor knees rather between . So it really depends which opinion one follows

Answer (score 0):

It is not permissible for women to watch sports such as wrestling and swimming on television, but sports such as football and volleyball are permissible because they cover most of their body by clothes.

If watching a football match and looking at naked parts of the body is likely to do the sin, then watching football is not permissible. So this is completely a personal feeling and cannot be given the same rule for everyone.

[ref](https://makarem.ir/main.aspx?typeinfo=21&lid=0&catid=530&mid=263265)